# android remove keyboard in form

Tags: android, validation, android-keypad

I have an Android application with a form.
When the user sends in the information by clicking on "Send",
the app validates the form.
If the problem is found, it scrolls up and shows a certain textView.

But how do I clear the keyboard? It takes in half of my screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show the keyboard:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myEdit);
InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
// only will trigger it if no physical keyboard is open
mgr.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

And to hide:

```
InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

This code was taken from http://www.androidguys.com/2009/11/12/how-to-showhide-soft-keyboard-programmatically-dev-tips-tools/

Comment: Tnx, but the problem is that it could be in any editText in the screen

Comment: You could do `editTextObject.requestFocus();` I am unable to test it now as I am on a computer without android sdk. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:imeOptions = "actionNext"` or `android:imeOptions = "actionDone"` in xml